# Create an array with a string key from wpdb->get_results

Tags: wpdb, array

Using this code to get some data into a PHP array:

```
$currentProducts = array();
$currentProducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, feedid, size, price FROM products WHERE shopid = $shopid");
```

No problems getting the data into a normal PHP array.

How do I get the data into an array where the feedid is key, so I can easily and quickly check if a specific feedid exist in the array, remove a specific feedid element etc?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution:

```
$currentProducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT feedid, id, size, price FROM products WHERE shopid = $shopid", OBJECT_K);
```

The OBJECT_K parameter makes an associative array with feedid as key: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to do that but, all you need is a loop:

```
foreach ( $currentProducts as $currentProduct ) 
{
    $myNewArray[$currentProduct->feedid] = $currentProduct->size;//use whatever value you need
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to set the feedid as key first?

Comment: This sets the feedid as the key of the array $myNewArray   Do you mean you need the database table key to be the feedid?